# VLC/VLM output string duplicate module

Tags: vlc

i'd need to stream a subset of elementary stream within a videoclip using VLM as "Video On Demand" media type. Usually i do transcoding so my output stream is something like that

```
#duplicate{dst="transcode{<options>}, select="es=x,es=y,..."}
```

in the case of no transcoding, i would like to use "duplicate" module but with an empty (or passthrought ) "dst" chain. Is it possible still to use "duplicate" or i have to use "es" module to select elementary streams instead?

in that case, i have some problems with the "es" module...could someone help me?

thanks in advice, excuse me for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
duplicate{dst=std{access=udp{ttl=10},mux=ts,dst=239.192.15.15:1234},dst=rtp{ttl=10,mux=ts,dst=10.0.0.4,port=5004}}
```

An example on how to address the dst. you must send it somewhere right?

Regarding the ES I think you're on the right track

```
es=: duplicate only the elementary stream with the selected id.
```

[VLC Duplicate help](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch03.html#id347397)